# How to wait for variable in window object before render a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component that need to access variable inside window object. But it renders before it loaded. So is there any solution delay that component render until variable will exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to wrap it into a

```js
this.$nextTick(() => {
  // ur code here
})
```

nextTick is a function which waits till the dom is complete loaded and executes the content inside.

Comment: It doesn't work like that... $nextTick waits for the document to load, after that it renders, but in the meanwhile it can be some variables that are loading into the window object. It has been an issue for me.